# how can i fetch different data results in single row of bootstrap slider using php and mysql

Tags: javascript, php, css, mysqli, twitter-bootstrap-3

i want to create a dynamic bootstrap slider using php by fetching data from mysql. what the problem i am facing is i am getting all similar products in single row of slide. how can i get multiple data in single row of slide.i want to display different products in different columns of bootstrap.in this slider it contains two classes of js which are **item** and **item active**.i am getting same images on item and item active individually but as seperate slider those both are showing different images.i want to get all different data in different columns in all classes.
...FYR i had included my images

```html
<div class="row msp" id="most-sold"><!--most sold product slider-->
          <h3/>Most Sold out Products</h3>
            
            <?php 
            $msp_query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE cat_tag = 'mostsoldout' AND sales_completed > 0 ORDER BY sales_completed DESC";
            $msp_run = mysqli_query($con,$msp_query);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($msp_run)>0){
            ?>
            <div id="carousel-example-generic2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              
              <!-- Wrapper for slides -->

              <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <?php 
                $check = 0;
                while ($msp_row = mysqli_fetch_array($msp_run)) {
                  $pro_id = $msp_row['id'];
                  $pro_image = $msp_row['image1'];
                  $pro_desc = $msp_row['description'];
                  $pro_price = $msp_row['cost'];
                  $pro_rating = $msp_row['rating'];
                  $pro_title = $msp_row['title'];
                  $check = $check + 1;
                  if($check == 1){
                    echo "<div class='item active'>";
                  }else{
                    echo "<div class='item'>";
                  }
                ?>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <a href="#"><div class="panel">
                  <img src="images/<?php echo $pro_image;?>" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="item" >
                  <p><?php echo $pro_desc;?></p>
                  <p>Price:<span class="fa fa-rupee"><?php echo $pro_cost;?>/-</span></p>
                  <p>Rating: <span style="color:gold;" class="fa fa-star"></span><span style="color:gold;" class="fa fa-star"></span><span style="color:gold;" class="fa fa-star"></span><span style="color:gold;" class="fa fa-star"></span> </p>
                  <h5 style="color:#E80C4F;"><?php echo $pro_title?></h5>
                </div></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <a href="#"><div class="panel">
                  <img src="images/<?php echo $pro_image;?>" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="item" >
                  <p><?php echo $pro_desc;?></p>
                  <p>Price:<span class="fa fa-rupee"><?php echo $pro_cost;?>/-</span></p>
                  <p>Rating: <span style="color:gold;" class="fa fa-star"></span><span style="color:gold;" class="fa fa-star"></span><span style="color:gold;" class="fa fa-star"></span><span style="color:gold;" class="fa fa-star"></span> </p>
                  <h5 style="color:#E80C4F;"><?php echo $pro_title?></h5>
                </div></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <a href="#"><div class="panel">
                  <img src="images/<?php echo $pro_image;?>" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="item" >
                  <p><?php echo $pro_desc;?></p>
                  <p>Price:<span class="fa fa-rupee"><?php echo $pro_cost;?>/-</span></p>
                  <p>Rating: <span style="color:gold;" class="fa fa-star"></span><span style="color:gold;" class="fa fa-star"></span><span style="color:gold;" class="fa fa-star"></span><span style="color:gold;" class="fa fa-star"></span> </p>
                  <h5 style="color:#E80C4F;"><?php echo $pro_title?></h5>
                </div></a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <?php
                 }
                ?>
              </div>
              <!-- Controls -->
              <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span style="color:black"; class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
              </a>
              <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic2" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span style="color:black"; class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
              </a>
            </div>
            <?php
          }else{
            echo "<center>No products yet</center>";
          }
            ?>

          </div><!--most sold product slider-->
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop creates a new "item" and three "col-md-4" for every product. You need to have only one "col-md-4", and implement a check to start a new "item" every third time.

It is not a very complex thing to do, but it can be tricky to position all your checks and opening and closing tags correctly inside and outside your loop. Always remember to close the last `div` when you exit the loop.

After our back and forth in the comments. This should work as your `index.php` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">

    <title>Clickart</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/animated.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-dropdownhover.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>
    <!---->

    <!---->
    <!--container ends here-->
      <div class="container-fluid"> 

        <!--upper row bar starts here-->

        <div class="row msp" id="most-sold"><!--most sold product slider-->
          <h3/>Most Sold out Products</h3>

            <?php 
            $msp_query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE cat_tag = 'mostsoldout' AND sales_completed > 0 ORDER BY sales_completed DESC";
            $msp_run = mysqli_query($con,$msp_query);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($msp_run)>0){
            ?>
            <div id="carousel-example-generic2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

              <!-- Wrapper for slides -->

              <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                  <?php 
                  $check = 0;
                  $full_page = 0;
                  while ($msp_row = mysqli_fetch_array($msp_run)) {
                    $pro_id = $msp_row['id'];
                    $pro_image = $msp_row['image1'];
                    $pro_desc = $msp_row['description'];
                    $pro_price = $msp_row['cost'];
                    $pro_rating = $msp_row['rating'];
                    $pro_title = $msp_row['title'];
                    $check = $check + 1;
                    if($full_page == 0){
                      if($check == 1){ ?>
                        <div class='row item active'>
                      <?php } else { ?>
                        </div><div class='row item'>
                      <?php }
                    } ?>
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                        <a href="#">
                          <div class="panel">
                            <img src="images/<?php echo $pro_image;?>" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="item" >
                            <p><?php echo $pro_desc;?></p>
                            <p>Price:<span class="fa fa-rupee"><?php echo $pro_cost;?>/-</span></p>
                            <p>Rating: <span style="color:gold;" class="fa fa-star"></span><span style="color:gold;" class="fa fa-star"></span><span style="color:gold;" class="fa fa-star"></span><span style="color:gold;" class="fa fa-star"></span> </p>
                            <h5 style="color:#E80C4F;"><?php echo $pro_title?></h5>
                          </div>
                        </a>
                      </div>
                  <?php
                    $full_page++;
                    if($full_page == 2) {
                      $full_page = 0;
                    }
                   } ?>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Controls -->
              <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span style="color:black"; class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
              </a>
              <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic2" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span style="color:black"; class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
              </a>
            </div>
            <?php
          }else{
            echo "<center>No products yet</center>";
          }
            ?>

        </div><!--most sold product slider-->

      </div>

    <!--container ends here-->

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
     <script src="js/bootstrap-dropdownhover.min.js"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gregkos thank you very much answeing. But if i am placing only one colum only one item is dispalyed in one row of slide and another item appears on another row of slider. My slider totally contains two slider rows which each consist of three items. For 3 items in single slide of one row. Like this if i have 15 products total and by dividing 3 of them in each slider row total five slider rows will exist. This is how my slider works. Basing upon this if i maintain one column with single item total 15 products will go into 15 slider rows but not by dividing into 3(products)/5(slider rows)

Comment: one more thing found is the same sql query applying on all of my columns so the same data is repaeting

Comment: Please see my updated answer and let me know if it works for you. :)

Comment: Dear gregkos it worked but after 3 items remaining items came below the slider i want to dispay 3 items in one time slider after 3 items have to come in another slider. i will put screenshot for your reference –https://www.dropbox.com/s/e71fzd4n969oen8/screenshot%20of%20products.png?dl=0

Comment: Are you using a specific slider that I can see online? The correct format varies based on the structure of each slider. If it is your own, can you update the question with your complete relevant code?

Comment: Dear gregkos first of all thank you for your patience that you are showing to help me. I am using the bootstrap carousel slider.in that slider we can have only one big image but i divided it as 3 columns to show as 3 items. here is the slider link http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel.   in this slider in first slide i need 3 products and in second slide remaining 3 products like this the sliders have to continue until the last product

Comment: Dear greg i tried in several ways it's not working but thank you for for your support.Do you know any other slider to display products using php. If you know please suggest me..

Comment: Please provide more information on what exactly doesn't work. Also, since the code should work, it would be best if you provided your full code (this file), any CSS you're using except the Bootstrap core, as well as a sample of your db structure. There are millions of other sliders, but what you want is simple and should be working just fine with Carousel. Here is a working version with static data: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FIBM7RCU1IYY (Change orientation to view correctly)

Comment: Also fixed an issue with a </div> on my answer code, maybe that was your issue?

Comment: Please see updated answer and remove your Dropbox link with your project files, as well as, and most importantly, your db password(!)

Comment: Dear greg i will check with your answer i will let you know tomorrow morning because it is midnight 2:00pm here. Thank you for your suggestions

Comment: Dear gregkos thank you, thank you very much for your help.i am getting the result perfectly now. i don't know how to to say you my happiness.if you help people like this for many students like me you will be guidance for us.thank you very much greg.thankyou for your patience showed to me.i wan tto keep in touch with you can i have fb link of email or any way to contact u

Comment: can you explain me what the mistake i ha done and how you corrected it.

Comment: Thank you for your kind words. The best way to contact me is through my Twitter, which you can find on my profile here. I've updated my answer to fully explain what's going on. If it really solved your problem, remember to select it as a correct answer.

Comment: Thank you greg you are my life saver 